# Arduino send HEX values via XBee

Tags: arduino, xbee

I'm trying to send HEX values via XBee from a Arduino to digi's Xbee program XCTU. But i have some problems with some bytes that i cant send

The list of bytes i cant send:
0x11
0x13
0x7D
0x7E
0x81
0xEC
0xEE

If i use any other bytes i can see it in the XCTU console window and i get a response back to the Arduino

I have enabled API mode (AP=1) on both of the Xbee's. Im using the XBee lib linked from Arduino web site (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Libraries)
My code looks like this:

```
#define XBEE_RX_PIN 8
#define XBEE_TX_PIN 9
SoftwareSerial xbeeSerial(XBEE_RX_PIN, XBEE_TX_PIN);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    xbeeSerial.begin(9600);
    xbee.begin(xbeeSerial);

}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("Send next 255 msg:");
    uint8_t testMsg[1] = { 0x0 };
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 0xFF; i++)
    {
        test2[0] = i;
        Tx16Request testTx = Tx16Request(0xFFFF, testMsg, sizeof(testMsg));

        xbee.send(testTx);
        Serial.print("Message send: ");
        Serial.println(test2[0], HEX);

        if (xbee.readPacket(5000)) {      
            Serial.println("SUCCESS");
        }
        else if (xbee.getResponse().isError()) {
            Serial.println("isError");
        }
        else {
            Serial.println("No Response");
        }
    }
    Serial.println("");
    delay(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AP=1, you can't send some special bytes like:

- 0x7E (start of frame)
- 0x11/0x13 (XOn XOff)
- ...

As mentioned in the XBee documentation (XBee®XBee-PRO® ZB RF Modules manual 90000976_W.pdf, starting page 112), you should use AP=2 mode which allows you to transmit these special bytes by escaping them:

> **Escape characters.**
>   When sending or receiving a UART data frame, specific data values must be
>   escaped (flagged) so they do not interfere with the data frame sequencing.
>   To escape an interfering data byte, insert 0x7D and follow it with the byte to be escaped XOR’d with 0x20.
>   Note that, if not escaped, 0x11 and 0x13 is sent as is.
>   
>   **Data bytes that need to be escaped:**
>   - 0x7E – Frame Delimiter
>   - 0x7D – Escape
>   - 0x11 – XON
>   - 0x13 – XOFF
>   
>   **Example** - Raw UART Data Frame (before escaping interfering bytes):
>   - 0x7E 0x00 0x02 0x23 **0x11** 0xCB
>   0x11 needs to be escaped which results in the following frame:
>   - 0x7E 0x00 0x02 0x23 **0x7D 0x31** 0xCB
>   Note In the above example, the length of the raw data (excluding the checksum) is 0x0002 and the checksum of the non-escaped data (excluding frame delimiter and length) is calculated as:
>   0xFF - (0x23 + 0x11) = (0xFF - 0x34) = 0xCB.

Hope this helps